# Plugin Error after Wordpress update

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My hosting provider automatically updated to 4.5 and it resulted in an error with the Visual Composer plugin.

I DID READ THESE POSTS:
[Plugin throwing TypeError after Wordpress 4.5 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605420/plugin-throwing-typeerror-after-wordpress-4-5-update)

[Visual composer doesn't load and gives TypeError: _.template(...).trim is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633822/visual-composer-doesnt-load-and-gives-typeerror-template-trim-is-not-a)

[Uncaught TypeError: $template.get is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641618/uncaught-typeerror-template-get-is-not-a-function)

And replaced the html2element function with the one provided. However, as many people commented on these posts, I get a new error:

```
composer-view.js?ver=4.6.1:139 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
```

Here is my function:

```
html2element: function(html) {
            var $template, attributes = {},
                template = html;
            $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim()), _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
                attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
            }), this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), this.renderContent()
        },
```

The error seems to be coming from this line:

```
$template.get(0).attributes
```

Has anyone figured out how to fix it ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Had the same problem with 4.5 update and tried everything I found but it was still not working.

Finally, I replaced my theme visual composer plugin (v4.7 something) by a recent one (4.11.2, google js_composer.zip).

I just replaced the entire directory content, it works fine.

Comment: you're a life saver !

Comment: This one worked, but it's basically a version of the standalone visual composer plugin installed on a site that you should pay for and not copy from another site. I download the zip-file in your answer for testing and it worked. Then I purchased the plugin (about $30) ( https://vc.wpbakery.com/visual-composer-license/) so I could sleep at night as well :-) It's up to people how they would do this, but I think this is good to know.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Are you sure that you have not paid twice ? It was in your theme for a reason, there are often agreements between themes and plugins makers. But you're right, it's an emergency patch. I let license problem up to everyone :)

Comment: @FLX - I actually did pay more then I needed to,  but I don't care. It would cost me more in terms of time to get involved with the theme makers to make them fix t he issue. The latest version of Bridge theme does not include the correct version of Visual Composer, not for now anyway.

Comment: Worked for me. It was hard finding the new version of VC. Working link as of today is http://www.solidfiles.com/v/43XgaXWwYV6AZ/dl. You will need a VPN to get access to this page. In few countries its restricted. You will also need a rar utility to extract its contents. Then use the js_composer.zip file and you are done. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Graham, hi

I think problem not in jquery, but in underscore that using in js_composer.

In render method pass wrong html object to html2element method like this:

```
 this.html2element(_.template($shortcode_template_el.html(),
            this.model.toJSON(),
             vc.templateOptions.default));
```

But this code send to html2element method html object as function that not have any properties or something else. It happen because _.template function from underscore library not render first arg(html template) before second arg not have a valid variable for first arg.

In my opinion to solve this problem need do this:

```
this.html2element(_.template($shortcode_template_el.html()));
```

This 2 methods render and html2element https://gist.github.com/maximspokoiny/34ad60ad90944f8a80c6fc093873a807/9fb041d2b12249fe4391f986f4e7e6a08f57c6b3#file-gistfile1-txt

i using js_composer 4.7.4 and wordpress 4.5.2 and this solve problem.

Thanks!

**UPDATED:**
Sorry, in html2element need too one change, from:

```
            if ( _.isString( html ) ) {
            this.template = _.template( html );
            $template = $( this.template( this.model.toJSON(), vc.templateOptions.default ).trim() );
        } else {
            this.template = html;
            $template = html;
        }
```

to:

```
            if ( _.isString( html ) ) {
            this.template = _.template( html );
            $template = $( this.template( this.model.toJSON(), vc.templateOptions.default ).trim() );
        } else {
            this.template = html;
            $template = $( this.template( this.model.toJSON(), vc.templateOptions.default ).trim() );
        }
```

Comment: This only works "a bit". You can edit elements, but not add any.